# Preserve `this` with recursive setImmediate()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Salam (means Hello:))

In my node.js app, I need to use `setImmediate()` to recessively call a function and keep its context intact for next execution.

Consider following example:

```
var i=3;

function myFunc(){
    console.log(i, this);
    --i && setImmediate(arguments.callee);
}

myFunc();
```

Output:

```
3 // a regular `this` object
2 { _idleNext: null, _idlePrev: null, _onImmediate: [Function: myFunc] }
1 { _idleNext: null, _idlePrev: null, _onImmediate: [Function: myFunc] }
```

As you can see, after first execution `this` is overwritten. How should I work around this?

Comment: To editors: don't make so minor edit suggestions, they block other more important edits for no reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
function myFunc(){
    console.log(i, this);
    --i && setImmediate(myFunc.bind(this));
}
```

As you may notice, I removed `arguments.callee`: [its use is deprecated and forbidden in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee).